# SharePoint 2013 REST API: Firing Content Organizer Rules

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to upload files to a Drop Off Library in SharePoint and then adding metadata to the files to have them properly routed through the Content Organizer. However, after I add all the required column metadata for the content type, the file doesn't get routed or moved.

I can then go to SharePoint through my browser and simply hit submit on the file's metadata page, and the Content Organizer rules are fired.

I am looking for a way to fire the Content Organizer rules through the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

I know that when viewing Content Organizer settings via SharePoint, that there is a Submission Points section. Are you hitting this exact page with your API call? If you navigate to Site Settings | Site Administration (heading) | Content Organizer Settings you can view the page.

For more information about the Content Organizer, see here:

(SharePoint 2010, should still mostly apply for 2013) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-c78a5dc3-672e-4723-9a29-52b8da35a4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US